# Swift and AudioFormatGetProperty(_:_:_:_:_:)

Tags: swift, memory-management, core-foundation

I want to know how to manage unmannaged CFType AudioFormatGetProperty() with swift.

This function is low level API, and some kAudioFormatProperty_XXX returns
CFType object without annotation. According to Documentation, it says

> The caller is responsible for releasing the returned string.
>
> The caller must call the CFRelease function for the returned dictionary.

```
kAudioFormatProperty_FormatName
kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelLayoutName
kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelLayoutSimpleName
kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelName
kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelShortName
kAudioFormatProperty_ID3TagToDictionary
```

Swift has NO CFRelease support, so I think in this case caller have to do something like CFRelease.
Would you please give some advice?

My code snippet follows:

```
var aclSize : Int = 0
let aclPtr : UnsafePointer<AudioChannelLayout>? =
    CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetChannelLayout(desc, &aclSize)

var nameSize : UInt32 = 0
let err1 : OSStatus =
    AudioFormatGetPropertyInfo(kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelLayoutName,
                               UInt32(aclSize), aclPtr, &nameSize)

let count : Int = Int(nameSize) / MemoryLayout<CFString>.size
let ptr : UnsafeMutablePointer<CFString> =
    UnsafeMutablePointer<CFString>.allocate(capacity: count)

let err2 : OSStatus =
    AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelLayoutName,
                           UInt32(aclSize), aclPtr, &nameSize, ptr)

// do something here

ptr.deallocate() // Is this same as CFRelease(cfstringref)?
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found better solution for AudioFormatGetProperty().

**Simple solution:**

kAudioFormatProperty_* like FormatName or ChannelLayoutName return single CFString value.

In this case I can use following with ARC support. No need to release manually.

```
//
var formatSize : UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout<CFString>.size)
var format : CFString!
let err : OSStatus =
    AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_FormatName,
                           asbdSize, asbdPtr, &formatSize,
                           &format)
formatString = String(format as NSString)

//
var nameSize : UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout<CFString>.size)
var name : CFString!
let err : OSStatus =
    AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelLayoutName,
                           UInt32(aclSize), aclPtr,
                           &nameSize, &name)
layoutString = String(name as NSString)
```

---

**NOTE:**

How to identify if "non-annoted CFType object is really unmanaged or not".

Followings are cheap debugging procedure I did in this question.
I believe this is bad know-how, so I would like to know more better way.

1) Put some check for CFType's RetainCount.

If it is huge value like 1152921504606846975, then it is constant - no need to release().

```
let ptr : UnsafeMutablePointer<CFString> = ...
CFShow(ptr.pointee) // to confirm it is live
Swift.print(CFGetRetainCount(ptr.pointee)) // to check retainCount
```

2) If it is small value like 2 or 3, then try to autorelease it like:

```
let unmanaged = Unmanaged<CFString>.passUnretained(ptr.pointee)
_ = unmanaged.autorelease()
```

3) If it immediately crash (within runloop), it is managed (may or may not be by ARC)

4) If it runs as is, I assume it is not managed (so autorelase handles retainCount)

---

**Update:**

This is another test via Playground.

Following shows RetainCount changed from 3 to 2.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

let avacl : AVAudioChannelLayout? =
    AVAudioChannelLayout(layoutTag: kAudioChannelLayoutTag_AAC_5_1)
var unmanaged : Unmanaged<CFString>? = nil
do {
    let aclPtr : UnsafePointer<AudioChannelLayout> = avacl!.layout
    var aclSize : Int = MemoryLayout<AudioChannelLayout>.size +
        (Int(aclPtr.pointee.mNumberChannelDescriptions) - 1) *
        (MemoryLayout<AudioChannelDescription>.size)
    var nameSize : UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout<CFString>.size)

    let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<CFString>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    defer { ptr.deallocate() }
    _ = AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelLayoutName,
                               UInt32(aclSize), aclPtr, &nameSize, ptr)
    _ = ptr.move() // make CFString managed

    unmanaged = Unmanaged<CFString>.passUnretained(ptr.pointee)
    CFGetRetainCount(unmanaged?.takeUnretainedValue())
}
CFGetRetainCount(unmanaged?.takeUnretainedValue())
```

Following shows RetainCount changed from 4 to 2. (2 drop when out-of-scope)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

let avacl : AVAudioChannelLayout? =
    AVAudioChannelLayout(layoutTag: kAudioChannelLayoutTag_AAC_5_1)
var unmanaged : Unmanaged<CFString>? = nil
do {
    let aclPtr : UnsafePointer<AudioChannelLayout> = avacl!.layout
    var aclSize : Int = MemoryLayout<AudioChannelLayout>.size +
        (Int(aclPtr.pointee.mNumberChannelDescriptions) - 1) *
        (MemoryLayout<AudioChannelDescription>.size)
    var nameSize : UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout<CFString>.size)

    var name : CFString!
    _ = AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelLayoutName,
                           UInt32(aclSize), aclPtr, &nameSize, &name)

    unmanaged = Unmanaged<CFString>.passUnretained(name!)
    CFGetRetainCount(unmanaged?.takeUnretainedValue())
}
CFGetRetainCount(unmanaged?.takeUnretainedValue())
```